# How to call core bluetooth protocol in another class?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I started developing an app using core bluetooth protocol. The app can scan , connect/disconnect and control the device. In ControlViewController i add the side menu (i used swrevealviewcontroller) for the settings part.

When i click the side menu, the list of settings appear. When i click one of the setting it should be displaying again the controller part but with one of the settings pop-upview/alertview.

Example:   In Control class
      Menu Button > clicked > list of settings appeared(another class) > click one of the settings > show again the controller with pop-up(alert view with Yes or No option).

//

Control Class

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    if (central.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn)
    {
        // In a real app, you'd deal with all the states correctly

        return;

    }

    [self scan];


    // The state must be CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn...

    // ... so start scanning

}
```

//this is where i call the controller class 
Side Menu View Controller

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        ControlViewController *controller =[[ControlViewController alloc]init];
        [controller setHighLow];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to use the singleton pattern maybe? a SettingsClass, that should handle that kind of values, and your ViewController ask it wether some stuff are allowed or not?

Comment: If you're using core-bluetooth and you want to navigate to another view don't disconnect yet from the device. You should call the metho from class A to your settings class but take note on where you init CBCentralManager, didUpdatePeripheral will get called.